# Button icons are making button names undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, button, icons

When I put an icon inside a button, the name and the value property of the button becomes `undefined`.

```
listSpendings() {
    var mapped = this.props.money.transes.slice(0).reverse().map(trans => {
      return (
        <div key={trans._id} className="smoothbackground z-depth-3">
        <li key={trans._id} className="collection-item" style={{
        textDecoration: trans.crossedOut ? "line-through" : "none"
        }}> {trans.who} spent ${trans.amount} on {trans.info}
        <button onClick={this.handleClickChange} type="submit" className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light align-right-button" name="CrossOut" value={trans._id}>
          X
        </button>
        </li>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return mapped;
  }
```

This function works without any issues. This is the handleClickChange,

```
handleClickChange = event => {this.setState({ name: event.target.name, transId: event.target.value}); console.log(event.target.name);}
```

`console.log(event.target.name);` logs `CrossOut` like it should. Because that's the button's name.

However, when I put `<i class="material-icons">delete</i>` instead of the `X` you see in the code, `console.log(event.target.name);` logs `undefined`.

`<i class="material-icons">delete</i>` is a delete icon and it properly gets displayed on the screen, inside the button. In any case, I've also tried another icon. This is the trash icon from bootstrap.

```
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
</svg>
```

This one also gets displayed but the `console.log(event.target.name);` also logs `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`svg` element does not have `name` attribute.

```
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trash" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
</svg>
```

If you use `console.log(event.target.fill)`, you will get `currentColor`. Because, `svg` element contains `fill` attribute. In case of `console.log(event.target.hello)`, you will get `undefined`. That's because, there is no `hello` attribute in this HTML element currently.

**Edit**
Please, check if there is any defined eventlistener for `svg` elements.

Comment: OP's `svg` element is not the target of the click event so it isn't really clear what question you are answering here.

Comment: try and console.log(event.target) to see the issue

Comment: @ArasUludağ Please, check if there is any defined eventlistener for `svg` elements.